# How create a View, that contains Buttons and a List within the same Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

What syntax (xml and java) should I use to create a View, which would have a couple of buttons ("Next" and "Back") at the top of the screen, and a List, located below the buttons?
I have tried the following, but it did not work at all:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

FirstScreen.java:

```
public class FirstScreen extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String [] entries = {"one","two","three"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,entries);
        ListView lv = new ListView(this,null,R.id.ListView01);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work at all"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XML layout that should work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hello"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Back"/>       
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/your_list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And for the Java code.

```
...
String[] entries = { "one", "two", "three" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entries);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

I hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Do not forget to mark an accepted answer, you can see how in the FAQ under "How do I ask questions here?".

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this for your listview ID if you want to use a ListActivity

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```